# How to set the composite primary key for owned entity types using entity framework core 3.1.1?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I am using asp.net core 3.1 with efcore 3.1.1 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 3.1.1 to develop graphql APIs.

Here goes my code details:

**Articles.cs**

```
public class Articles
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    public string PublishedDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RelatedArticlesSchema> RelatedArticles { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RelatedEntityId> RelatedCountries { get; set; }
}
```

**RelatedArticlesSchema.cs**

```
public class RelatedArticlesSchema
{
    [JsonProperty("ArticleId")]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RelatedEntityId> RelatedCountries { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PartitionKey")]
    public string PublishedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**RelatedEntityId.cs**

```
public class RelatedEntityId
{
    public int IdVal { get; set; }
}
```

**SampleDbContext.cs**

```
public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Articles> Articles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Countries> Countries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var converter = new NumberToStringConverter<int>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().Property(e => e.LanguageId).HasConversion(converter);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().HasPartitionKey(o => o.LanguageId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries, a =>
        {
            a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("Articlesid");
            a.Property<int>("id");
            a.Property(o => o.IdVal);
        }

        ).OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedArticles, a =>
        {
            a.OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries, a =>
            {
                a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid");
                a.Property<int>("id");
                a.Property(o => o.IdVal);
            }

            );
            a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("Articlesid");
            a.Property<int>("id");
            a.Property(o => o.ArticleId);
            a.Property(o => o.Title);
            a.Property(o => o.PublishedDate);
        }

        ).OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedResources, a =>
        {
            a.OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries, a =>
            {
                a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid");
                a.Property<int>("id");
                a.Property(o => o.IdVal);
            }

            );
            a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("Articlesid");
            a.Property<int>("id");
            a.Property(o => o.ArticleId);
            a.Property(o => o.Title);
            a.Property(o => o.PublishedDate);
        }

        );
    }
}
```

Here goes the data in CosmosDB for the collection: Articles

```
{
  "ArticleId": 100,
  "PublishedDate": "12/1/2020 2:43:00 AM",
  "Author": null,
  "LanguageId": 37,
  "RelatedCountries": [
    {
      "IdVal": 1
    }
  ],
  "RelatedArticles": [
    {
      "ArticleId": 101,
      "Title": "Article_101",
      "RelatedCountries": [
        {
          "IdVal": 1
        }
      ],
      "PublishedDate": "5/26/2020 5:55:00 AM"
    },
    {
      "ArticleId": 102,
      "Title": "Article_102",
      "RelatedCountries": [
        {
          "IdVal": 1
        },
        {
          "IdVal": 2
        }
      ],
      "PublishedDate": "8/12/2020 4:57:00 AM"
    },
    {
      "ArticleId": 103,
      "Title": "Article_103",
      "RelatedCountries": [
        {
          "IdVal": 1
        },
        {
          "IdVal": 2
        },
        {
          "IdVal": 3
        }
      ],
      "PublishedDate": "8/20/2020 6:30:00 AM"
    },
    {
      "ArticleId": 104,
      "Title": "Article_104",
      "RelatedCountries": [
        {
          "IdVal": 10
        }
      ],
      "PublishedDate": "9/17/2020 6:06:00 AM"
    },
    {
      "ArticleId": 105,
      "Title": "Article_105",
      "RelatedCountries": [
        {
          "IdVal": 11
        }
      ],
      "PublishedDate": "11/26/2020 1:02:00 AM"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting the below mentioned error:

> The property 'RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid' cannot be added to the type 'RelatedArticlesSchema.RelatedCountries#RelatedEntityId' because there was no property type specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a shadow state property the property type must be specified.

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue

Comment: As the error says, there's no `RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid` property in any of those classes. You should configure each entity separately in `OnModelCreating`, not try to configure one inside the other. Even if the syntax seems to suggest you can nest and nest the configuration, it doesn't work

Comment: I used the article for reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to update your dbcontext class as follows:**

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedContacts);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountryGroups);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedTaxTags);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedArticles, a =>
        {
            a.ToJsonProperty("RelatedArticles");
            a.OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries);
        }

        );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedResources, a =>
        {
            a.ToJsonProperty("RelatedArticles");
            a.OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries);
        }

        );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsOne(p => p.Provisions);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsOne(p => p.ResourceGroup);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsOne(p => p.Disclaimer);
```

Thanks @AndriySvyryd for the documentation:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/f70c3b62e49169f858c087d0cc22ee3edf307933#diff-4301fc6ef06589dd6e5e63debdd80f68L289

Comment: Most of those navigations aren't present on `Articles`. But yes, this is better if you don't need to override the default shadow PKs

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a composite FK, since the principal has a composite PK and declare the shadow property first:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().Property(e => e.LanguageId).HasConversion(converter);
modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().HasPartitionKey(o => o.LanguageId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>()
    .OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries, a =>
    {
        a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("Articlesid");
        a.Property<int>("id");
        a.Property(o => o.IdVal);
    })
    .OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedArticles, a =>
    {
        a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("Articlesid");
        a.Property<int>("id");
        a.Property(o => o.ArticleId);
        a.Property(o => o.Title);
        a.Property(o => o.PublishedDate);

        a.OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries, a =>
        {
            a.Property<int>("RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid");
            a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesid", "RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid");
            a.Property<int>("id");
            a.Property(o => o.IdVal);
        });
    })
    .OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedResources, a =>
    {
        a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("Articlesid");
        a.Property<int>("id");
        a.Property(o => o.ArticleId);
        a.Property(o => o.Title);
        a.Property(o => o.PublishedDate);

        a.OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries, a =>
        {
            a.Property<int>("RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid");
            a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesid", "RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid");
            a.Property<int>("id");
            a.Property(o => o.IdVal);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Andriy Svyryd for your response. I tried the 2nd option and now I am getting an error: The property 'RelatedArticlesSchemaArticlesidid' cannot be added to the type 'RelatedArticlesSchema.RelatedCountries#RelatedEntityId' because there was no property type specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a shadow state property the property type must be specified.\n

Comment: Oh, you also need to specify a composite FK, I updated the code.